# How does Logstash internally work with messages/events?

Tags: logstash

I'm new to Logstash, and I'm trying to understand how inputs, filters and outputs work together. I get that there's a variety of inputs, filters and outputs, but what I don't get is how Logstash works with messages internally.

Say I configure a syslog input, and I'd like syslog events to be shipped to log index as GELF. There's a syslog input I can use, and there's a GELF output I can use. However, is it my responsibility (using filters) to populate the correct GELF field based on values from the syslog event?

Should I look at events (from input filters) as an entity with named fields (sort of a key:value array), and then use filters to make sure that outputs can get hold of the right data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jordan Sissel said, think of it as a pipe on steroids, between input and output you can do what you want with the events, you can match parts of the message to field names using [grok](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok) or you can use [mutate](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate) to [remove fields](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate#remove_field), [regex style text replacement](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate#gsub), [add](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate#add_tag) or [remove](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate#remove_tag) tags. Once you have your data formatted how you want you can then send it to your output.